# shamir's scheme in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

I'm developing a secure key sharing mechanism for personal cloud users as a research project. For that I use Shamir's algorithm to split and reconstruct the key. I have to do that in client side. So I have to use JS or JQuery. If anyone have implemented this schema in Jquery help me.

Comment: if the key sharing done in server side key will be exposed to the server admin. so I want to split the key and save in different locations, in client side(JS).

Answer (score 0):

here I found this schema implemented in **java** but what I want is **JQuery**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/secretsharejava/